# Can I make pacman aware of packages installed manually?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, pacman

Due to my setup I cannot make use of pacman to actually install packages, however if I install a package from the Arch repositories manually by downloading and extracting it, eg:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/curl-7.26.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
tar -Jxvf curl-7.26.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz -C /
```

...is there a way to make pacman aware of it so that it can control future updates or un-installation?

Comment: In other words, is there an equivalent of [equivs](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/equivs) for Pacman? (I don't know.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're downloading packages manually, then it's easiest to install them with pacman:

```
pacman -U curl-7.26.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

That way they'll also get tracked like any other package. If the reason for this mode of operation was a broken system, just run pacman afterwards (when you can) and the reinstallation will take care of tracking.

Comment: And if I can't use pacman?

Comment: at minimum an entry under /var/lib/pacman/local, but that looks pretty inefficient to parse, so I bet it stores more info elsewhere. Would have to check its source.

Comment: also check out the "-r, --root <path>" option, since you may be able to use the host's pacman to do this.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a database entry somewhere, but I can't seem to find the information that I want.

Comment: looks like it doesn't and the database is the flat file based thing under /var/lib/pacman. That's what the man page suggests and running strings on the binary doesn't show any other viable path default.

Comment: The [readme](http://projects.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/README?id=ea79de21d82369e799fcdc6e71b45d9580a75099) isn't too clear on what the database actually **is**.

Comment: looking at _alpm_filecache_find it is clear even the caches are separate files, so just go try it.

Comment: We actually managed to get it working using `--root`, which I'd somehow overlooked. I'll mark this as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want pacman to manage the program for you, you have to install it with pacman.

<sup>`curl` is in core, why don't you just `pacman -S curl`?</sup>

Comment: The reason I can't do this is that I'm attempting to install packages in a mounted Arch image of a different architecture without emulating it. Thus I cannot use pacman.

Comment: It would have been helpful to have included that information in your question...

Comment: I thought I had made it pretty obvious that using pacman wasn't viable. Otherwise I would have **just used pacman**.

Comment: I disagree: your question is clearly in the past tense - once a package has been installed manually, can pacman be made aware of it? There is *nothing* in your question that suggests, implictly or explicitly, that pacman is not available to you.

Comment: Why would I want to install a package manually if I could just use pacman? Nevertheless, I understand your comment and will amend the question.

Comment: People do all sorts of things with their machines... I can only go on the information presented. Thank you for considering it.